# jQuery on() / living() issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

I've been learning jQuery these times. Somehow, I got a problem  using `on(event, [selectors], handler)` in jQuery.
I want to attach an event to some living elements ( maybe appanded to the tree later ), and I found two ways (in jQuery and vanilla JS) to achieve this.

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <th>
    <label>
     <input type="checkbox"  id="s-all" autocomplete="off">
      Select All
     </label>
   </th>
   <th>INFO</th>
   <th>PRICE</th>
   <th>AMOUNT</th>
   <th>Manu</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="is-checked" autocomplete="off"></td>
   <td><img src="image/img.jpg" alt="222"><a href="#">Umbrella</a></td>
   <td>$100</td>
   <td>
    <input type="button" class="minus" value="-">
    <input type="text" disabled value="1" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="button" class="add" value="+">
   </td>
    <td><a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="is-checked" autocomplete="off"></td>
    <td>
     <img src="image/img.jpg" alt="222"><a href="#">fake umbrella</a>
    </td>
    <td>$1</td>
    <td>
     <input type="button" class="minus" value="-">
     <input type="text" disabled value="1" autocomplete="off">
     <input type="button" class="add" value="+">
    </td>
    <td><a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <button id="add-item">Add one</button>
```

this is my HTML code and it's easy to achieve what I want with jQuery and vanilla JS. But the "vanilla way" seems a little inconvenient (I have to invoke `livingClick()` EACH TIME I manipulate the dom tree).

```
var del = document.getElementsByClassName( "delete" );
document.getElementById( "add-item" ).onclick = function() {
  var copy = document.querySelectorAll( "tr" )[1].cloneNode( true );
  document.getElementsByTagName( "table" )[0].children[0].appendChild( copy );
  console.log(  copy );
  livingClick();
};
function livingClick() {
  for( var i = 0; i < del.length; i++) {
    del[i].onclick = function() {
      var that = this.parentElement.parentElement;
      that.parentElement.removeChild( that );
    };
  }
}
livingClick();
```

I was wonder **how did jQuery achieve this in such a simple way**

```
$( "tbody" ).on( 'click', ".delete", function(e) {
    $( this ).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

I've also know there is `Mutation Observer` can detect the change of DOM tree, but it is not been updated since 2015(is that true?), while jQuery has deprecated `live()` for a long time.
Could anyone be kind to help me figure this out?

Comment: What is `living()`? Do you mean `.live()`?

Comment: oh right, i mean `live()`. Sorry. Thanks for correcting me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
$( "tbody" ).on( 'click', ".delete", function(e) {
    $( this ).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

jQuery treats it roughly like writing:

```
$( "tbody" ).on( 'click', function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is(".delete")) {
        (function(e) {
            $( this).parent().parent().remove();
        ).bind(e.target)(e);
    }
});
```

This takes advantage of event bubbling. When you click on a descendant of `tbody`, the event bubbles up from that element to `tbody`, and at each step of the bubbling `e.target` is the element at that level of the DOM hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks! It helps a lot.

Comment: But `$( this ),parent().parent()` in your jQuery code is actually  `body` element.. ..is it supposed to be in a more complex way in deep jQuery ?

Comment: Yeah, forgot that it needs to reset `this` in the callback.